# Css Dropdown Menu font color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

In my drop-down menu the font colour of "li" is white and while "hover" the colour change to black and i have drop-down menu also .When hover the sub menu of my products link, the font  colour products(li) changing to white my hover background is also white, here my question, how can I keep the colour of my "li" as black  ??

my stylesheet

```
#menu{width:auto; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-color: #000; height:32px; float:right; border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px ;}
#menu ul{list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:10px;}
#menu ul li{float: left; position: relative; margin-left:0px; height:29px; padding-top:3px;}
#menu ul li:active {color:#000;}
#menu ul li:hover{background-color: #f5f5f5; margin-left:0px; color:#000}
#menu ul li a{color: #fff; padding: 0 16px; line-height:25px; font-size:13px; font-family:arial; display: block; text-decoration:none; margin-left:0px;}
#menu ul li a:hover{background-color: #f5f5f5; margin-left:0px; color:#000;}
#menu ul li ul li{float: none; position: relative; margin-left:0px;}
#menu ul li ul{position: absolute; top:32px; left:0; display: none; background-color: #000; width:150px; margin-left:0px;}
#menu ul li:hover > ul{display: block; margin-left:0px; color:#000;}
#menu ul li ul li a{white-space: nowrap; line-height:25px; margin-left:0px;}
#menu ul li ul li ul{position: absolute; top:0; left:145px; display: none; background-color: #000; width:150px; margin-left:0px;}
```

my html code

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Has Submenu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: please provide fiddle for the same.

Comment: I would also advice to use classnames for the different levels of your menu. It really makes your css more readable, and you have less issues with conflicting rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  the following CSS:

```css
#menu ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
}
```

The problem was the anchor tag. No matter what color would you set for the `li`, the anchor tag has style `color: #fff`.